# How to link crashlytics to firebase?

Tags: firebase, crashlytics, firebase-crash-reporting

We have some apps reporting to crashlytics and we'd like to link them to firebase, (We have in total 6 apps, 3 android and 3 iOS) I successfully linked all of the iOS apps, then 2 weeks later (end of September) I started linking the Android ones, but every time I click the Firebase link in Crashlytics side-menu, I get redirected to a page where I'm asked to login with my Google-Apps account to link it, once I login with an "Owner" account of the Firebase project I get this error: "Could not load your Firebase projects." it's been like that for 4 weeks, though it worked before.
The link from the side menu is https://fabric.io/firebase_migration

I tried to use the following link from a similar post here (Just in case it's already linked and I need to unlink it first)

https://fabric.io/remove_firebase_crashlytics?clientId=android:my.app.id&projectId=my-firebase-project (Apparently nothing is linked), so I landed on a very similar page like the one from the Crashlytics side-menu and got almost the same error with slightly different wording "Unable to load Firebase projects"

Comment: Mike from Fabric & Firebase here. Best to contact support(at)fabric(dot)io so we can link into your specific case. Please share your project Firebase ids and google email address.

Comment: thanks @MikeBonnell, we already approached some of the Engineers during the Firebase Summit in Prague and sent these details, but I have more cases with similar issues using different accounts, I'll wait for this then I'll email you the rest of project examples.

Comment: We have the same problem. We have reached out to Firebase Support, but in the mean time can you let us know how you fixed it?